# Regex java split space + ,

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a simple problem. String looks like this:

```
storm, whatever1, fire,water and something else,earth
```

I would like to use String.split(" ... ") and split line for "," or "space + ,". Just dont want to have any space in any of string.
Result should be

```
String s[] = {"storm","whatever1","fire","water and something else","earth"};
```

Is it possible using regex?

Comment: What is the exact regex you are using, might be a problem there.

Comment: `split` uses regex, as indicated in the doc. splitting on `+` and removing spaces is simple : `"...".split("\\s*,\\s*");`

Comment: I can use .trim() after splitting but I would like to not do too many operations..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split using `\\s*,\\s*`. This will split on each `,` including zero or more [(`*`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) whitespaces [(`"\\s"`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) surrounding it from each side.

Comment: do. or do not. there is no try.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String source = "storm, whatever1, fire,water and something else,earth";
        for (String piece : source.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
        {
            System.out.println(piece);
        }
    }

}
```